# Git fetch interrupted and corrupted repository

Tags: git, github, version-control, repository, git-fetch

I ran `git fetch` and my laptop died while it was running. Now there is a .git folder but running any git command says `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`. Running `git init` says `Reinitialized existing Git repository in <directory>`

Comment: First: if there are potential good files in the work-tree, save those elsewhere now (on another machine)! Then: It's a good idea to run a file system consistency checker (which is OS-specific) on your laptop. Assuming that is OK and the `.git` directory is still problematic, check for a missing `.git/HEAD` file. If the `HEAD` file is missing, create one, using whichever branch you had checked out, or using `ref: refs/heads/master` if you don't know which branch.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly don't want to run `git init` if the repository already exists somewhere. Whenever the repository already exists you either want to clone it or fetch it.

The way to handle this situation depends on whether you had local changes that have not been pushed out to a remote yet.

The simplest case is that you had no changes (or you are willing to discard any local changes). In that case you can simply delete the entire entire directory and do a `git clone <remote>` from scratch to grab a pristine copy.

If you had important local changes then the comment offered by [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) should be your starting point, it should be converted to an Answer ;)